# How to pause layout updates during pan animation?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I've got a root view, using Auto Layout, that a user can dismiss by interactively swiping down on it, achieved through a pan gesture recognizer that adjust's the view's `frame.origin` property. There's a view in the top leading corner with the following constraints:

```
Top = Safe Area
Height == 50
Trailing >= Safe Area + 8
Leading = Safe Area + 16
```

When `origin.y` is anything other than `0.0`, the top Safe Area apparently changes, and the view jumps up. I'm trying to avoid this behavior. I tried applying an affine transform instead of manipulating the origin, but that didn't make a difference.

Is there any way to pause or freeze auto layout constraint evaluation while the animation is going on?

I'm testing in the iPhone SE simulator running iOS 11.3 (and I saw this in 11.2 as well).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement custom transitioning for a presented view controller, try using the `transitioningDelegate` property of `UIViewController` class. I've used this many times in the past(not interactively with a gesture though), and never had problems with subviews using AutoLayout. Here's some code that might help you out. I borrowed most of it from [this Github project](https://github.com/ThornTechPublic/InteractiveModal). I've also added a subview with the constraints you specified to the leading left of the root view and tested it on an iPhone X Simulator. Seemed to have worked without any issues.

```
@interface TransitionInteractor: UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL hasStarted;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL shouldFinish;

@end
```

And then in the class that conforms to the UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning protocol, implement the following methods:

```
@interface DismissAnimator : NSObject <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>

- (NSTimeInterval)transitionDuration:(nullable id <UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext {
    return 0.4f;
}

- (void)animateTransition:(id <UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext {
    UIViewController *fromViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
    UIViewController *toViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];
    if (!fromVC || !toVC)
        return;

    [transitionContext.containerView insertSubview:toVC.view belowSubview:fromVC.view];

    CGRect screenBounds = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
    CGFloat height = CGRectGetHeight(screenBounds);
    CGPoint bottomLeftCorner = CGPoint(x: 0, y: screenBounds.height)
    CGRect finalFrame = CGRectMake(0.0f, height, CGRectGetWidth(screenBounds), height);

    NSTimeInterval duration = [self transitionDuration:transitionContext];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
        fromVC.view.frame = finalFrame;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [transitionContext completeTransition:!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled];
    }];
}
```

And in the view controller file:

```
@interface PresentedViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) TransitionInteractor *interactor;

@end

@implementation PresentedViewController

- (void)handlePanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    CGFloat percentThreshold = 0.3f;

    // convert y-position to downward pull progress (percentage)
    CGPoint translation = [sender translationInView:self];
    CGFloat verticalMovement = translation.y / [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
    CGFloat downwardMovement = fmaxf(verticalMovement, 0.0f);
    CGFloat progress = fminf(downwardMovement, 1.0f);
    CGPoint velocity = [sender velocityInView:self];

    switch (sender.state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
            self.interactor.hasStarted = YES;
            [self.vc dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
            break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:
            self.interactor.shouldFinish = (velocity.y > 1000) ? YES : (progress > percentThreshold);
            [self.interactor updateInteractiveTransition:progress];
            break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled:
            self.interactor.hasStarted = NO;
            [self.interactor cancelInteractiveTransition];
            break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
            self.interactor.hasStarted = NO;
            self.interactor.shouldFinish ? [self.interactor finishInteractiveTransition] : [self.interactor cancelInteractiveTransition];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

@end
```

And set the transitioning delegate in your presenting view controller before you present this view controller. Implement the delegate methods as follows:

```
@interface PresentingViewController () <UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) TransitionInteractor *interactor;

@end

@implementation PresentingViewController

- (TransitionInteractor *)interactor {
    if (!_interactor) {
        _interactor = [TransitionInteractor new];
    }
    return _interactor;
}

#pragma mark - Navigation

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[PresentedViewController class]]) {
        PresentedViewController *destination = [segue destinationViewController];
        destination.transitioningDelegate = self;
        destination.interactor = self.interactor;
    }
}

#pragma mark - UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate

- (id <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animationControllerForDismissedController:(UIViewController *)dismissed {
    return [DismissAnimator new];
}

- (id <UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning>)interactionControllerForDismissal:(id <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animator {
    return self.interactor;
}

@end
```

Comment: I apologize. Calling it a "full screen" view was misleading, making it sound like it was a subview. It's actually the root view of the presented view controller. I updated the question to clarify. As far as I can tell, IB doesn't let you add an edge constraint to it.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I thought it was a UIView that you were trying to dismiss interactively. So is it a modally presented UIViewController that you want to dismiss using the pan gesture?

Comment: @Dov Alright, I edited my answer with a different solution approach. Let me know if that works